# Import json file in typescript Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, angular5

I am trying to import json file in typescript class like that

```
import * as nationalities from './mock/nationalities.json';
```

and it gives me an error

> Cannot find module './mock/nationalities.json'.

and to solve this issue I added this

```
declare module '*.json' {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

but it doesn't solve my issue and also  gives my another error exception

> Invalid module name in augmentation, module '*.json' cannot be found.

My Typescript version

> 2.9.2

Comment: _"I added this"_ where?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275995/angular4-how-do-access-local-json/51040504#51040504

Comment: You probably added the declaration in the same file of the import, its a common mistake, just make sure that you add it in typings.d.ts

Comment: json files are not packaged by default, see step 1 in my answer below + import path should be absolute see step 3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991237/how-to-import-json-file-into-a-typescript-file), here is complete answer for Angular 6+:

Suppose you added your json files into "json-dir" directory:

1. add "json-dir" into angular.json file :

   ```
   "assets": [
     "src/assets",
     "src/json-dir"
   ]
   ```
2. allow import of json modules to prevent from typescript errors:

   Angular 6: add to `typings.d.ts`

   ```
   declare module "*.json" {
       const value: any;
       export default value;
   }
   ```

   Angular 7+: add to `tsconfig.json`

   ```
   "compilerOptions": {
   ...
       "resolveJsonModule": true
   }
   ```
3. from your controller, service or anything else, simply import the file by using this **absolute path** from `/src` directory. For example:

   `import * as myJson from 'absolute/path/to/json/dir/json-file.json';`

> assuming source files are in `src/app` and json files in `src/absolute/path/to/json/dir`

Comment: I followed these exact steps and its still throwing the same issue. Where elase could I need to add a config?

Comment: error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../../../assets/data/countries.json'.

Comment: import path should be absolute